# Странность неявной типизации JS

Tags: javascript, типизация

Я только начал изучать JS, до этого (как и сейчас) кодю на C#.
Для меня неявная типизация JS - просто ужас! Появился конкретный кейс, код успешно не работает.

```
if (step + direction < 0) {
    document.writeln("outdown");
} else {
    step += direction;
    document.writeln(step);
}
```

При этом *step* в начале выполнения *0*, а *direction* *-1*. Вместо надписи *outdown* выводится "*0-1*". Я понимаю, что это происходить из-за того, что одна переменная не int, а string. Как это починить я не знаю.

Comment: Если `step=0` и `direction=-1`, то выводится в точности `outdown`. Вы явно что-то не договариваете. Например, то, что `step` и `direction` на самом деле не числа, а строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример, который я составил по вашему описанию работает корректно

```js
let step = 0;
let direction = -1;

if (step + direction < 0) {
    document.writeln("outdown");
} else {
    step += direction;
    document.writeln(step);
}
```

А вот этот выводит указанный Вами текст:

```js
let step = "0";
let direction = -1;

if (step + direction < 0) {
    document.writeln("outdown");
} else {
    step += direction;
    document.writeln(step);
}
```

Все дело в том, что во втором примере, а значит и у вас `step` не `0` а `"0"`, т.е. строка;

решать это можно либо неявным приведением к Number:

```
step = +step;
```

или явно вызывая функцию Number:

```
step = Number(step);
```

Comment: У меня было step = 0; но +step проблему решило. Спасибо!